# Is it good to use Threads in CLR SQL?

Tags: multithreading, sqlclr

There are 1,00,000 Update Statement available in a SQL table EexecuteQueue

Below is the Step I am planning to do.

Identify the Logical Processor of the Database server.

The queries available in the EexecuteQueue table will be split in to number of (logical processor-2) and execute in different thread.

My assumption is Instead of executing 1,00,000 update statement sequentially, threads will execute 25,000 update statements in parallel (If we have 4 Threads).

My Question 
Is my assumption correct?
Is it good to user Threads in CLRSQL?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> My assumption is Instead of executing 1,00,000 update statement sequentially, threads will execute 25,000 update statements in parallel (If we have 4 Threads). Is my assumption correct?

Yes, but is completely irrelevant. Doing 25k operations on 4 threads by no means implies is going to be faster than doing 100k operations on a single thread. Such an assumption is, at best, naive. You need to identify your bottlenecks and address them accordingly, depending on your findings. Read [How to analyse SQL Server performance](http://rusanu.com/2014/02/24/how-to-analyse-sql-server-performance/).

> Is it good to user Threads in CLRSQL?

No.

To speed up batch updates, use set based operations. Reduce number of round trips. Batch commit.

Comment: Is it good to split Threads in my Window application to call the CLR Stored Procedure 4 times with 25K Query execution each?

Comment: No, the only thing good is to measure performance and address bottlenecks. Random 'lets try this' are never a good approach. Besides, adding threads is by definition a bad idea when you can submit non-blocking async requests with [`BeginExecuteNonQuery`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.beginexecutenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx)